# mysql - create new column and conditionally populate the new column with data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to alter a table to add an additional column and populate the new column based on another column. For example I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | username   | role     |
+----+------------+----------+
| 1  |    foo     | admin    |
+----+------------+----------+
| 2  |    bar     | operator |
+----+------------+----------+
```

I want to add a column named `tenant` and based on the value in `role` column populate the value inside `tenent`:

```
+----+------------+----------+--------------+
| id | username   | role     | permissions  |
+----+------------+----------+--------------+
|  1 |    foo     | admin    |      *       |
+----+------------+----------+--------------+
|  2 |    bar     | operator |   limited    |
+----+------------+----------+--------------+
```

Is there a MySQL query that can be performed or will I need to create a script to do this?

Comment: Possibly a *generated* column would be better for this.

Comment: Have you looked at the `CASE` statement?  <https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/mysql-case-statement/#MySQL_CASE_Syntax>

Comment: *I want to add a column named tenant* - your desired results have a column *permissions*. What happened to *Tenant*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a *generated column*, something like the following. That way, when you update the *role*, the *Permissions* will automatically be correct:

```
alter table MyTable add column Permissions varchar(10) generated always as 
  (case when role='admin' then '*' else 'limited' end);
```